# Retrieving username from firestore and put in appbar title everytime I sign in using futurebuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When getting the username for the first time, there is no problem. But when signing out and then sign in the username is  not appearing except when I make hot reload.

```
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

Future<String> getusername() async {
final DocumentSnapshot users =
    await firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get();

return users.data()['username'];
}
```

in Appbar :

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    title: signedin == true
        ? FutureBuilder(
            future: getusername(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }

              return Text(snapshot.data);
            },
          )
        : Text("homepage"),
```

I've tried StreamBuilder but no result. Any help!

Comment: can you please show the rest of your code where the user signs out and in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `builder`

```
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) 
            return Text(snapshot.data);
          else 
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Comment: thanks, but same result, Firestore is retrieving null in the second time and when hot reload the name appears. Is this maybe because of using Futurebuilder ??